# How to detect Mobile Browser (PHP/Javascript) and then make image/text change?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Using wordpress for my new site, and I am putting together the content of my pages. But I'm struggling to come up with a way to detect a mobile browser, and then with the result, change the visibility of certain elements (text / images) on the page depending on whether it is being viewed from a mobile device or a computer.

Eg. If onmobile=true, , else .

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: maybe you should consider to do it on client side with responsive design and CSS...

Comment: I agree with MrTux.  Implementing a responsive design is usually done using a framework, take a look at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), for example.

Comment: Java or JavaScript? (and yes, it matters).

Comment: The best way is to use media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, you'll want to differentiate between screen sizes, rather than whether or not it's a mobile browser.

As commented, you'll be better off using css media queries. One of the existing css frameworks, such as bootstrap, can be a good way to achieve this, but you don't *have to* use a framework.

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    div.myClass {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Will make an item hidden on small screens (including mobile devices).

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    div.myClass {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Will make something hidden on large screens. From there, mix and match to achieve whatever effect you're after.

On bootstrap, you've got helper-classes such as `visible-md-block` and `hidden-xs` to fine-tune visibility on various screen sizes. See [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) for more info on that bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a mobile browser and edit by:

CSS:

```
#show{display:none;}
```

Javascript

```
function check{
    if(window.innerWidth <= 800 && window.innerHeight <= 600) {
        document.getElementById('#show').style.display= 'block' ;     
    } }
```